# How to update resource files without recompiling

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dll, resources

I have a .net core Web Application with localization. I have .resx files with traslations. Also, I have an api, that downloads new versions of translations. Old versions are being replaced by new versions, but to update resources in application I need to recompile it. Is this possible without recompiling? Maybe I need to rebuild resource dlls?

Comment: It depends on version of Net and compiling mode (16/32/64).  A Net dll needs same version of Net that was used to compile to run on a machine.

Comment: You could create your own resource provider and load them from a database have a look at the source to nopcomerce it shows you in great detail how to achieve this. I was able achieve it by studying their methods

Comment: If you mean that you want to use directly the .resx files without compiling them you can use [this](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries#dynamic-resource-management) library (disclaimer: written by me). It has a `ResXResourceManager` class that can be used as a regular `ResourceManager`. The `HybridResourceManager` supports overriding the compiled resources with .resx files if they are present, and finally, `DynamicResourceManager` supports generating resource files if you switch to a language that has no saved resource set yet.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg I used HybridResourceManager with CompiledAndResX, it edits resx file, but not dll. I still need to recompile application

Comment: The `HybridResourceManager` can _read_ the compiled resources from the .dlls and can _read and write_ .resx files. In `CompiledAndResX` mode the .resx content is accessed in the first place so you can even override the compiled resources by deploying also a .resx file for the same language. So it does _not_ edit the dlls. But it can use directly the resx files so you don't need to compile them into satellite resource dll files. Isn't this is what you asked for? Using .resx files without the need of compiling them?

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg Thanks, i did it :)

Answer (score 0):

Create your own razor page which all other pages will derive from as such.

One thing to bare in mind is that this, will fetch out to database but i think its just on compile time or a page refresh.

```
public abstract class CellaRazorPage<TModel> : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<TModel>
{
     private Localizer _localizer;       

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a localized resources
    /// </summary>
    public Localizer T
    {
        get
        {
            var serviceProviderContext = Context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<CellaDBContext>();
            Int32.TryParse(serviceProviderContext.Appsettings.Where(w => w.Key == Constants.FrontEndDefaultLanguageId).FirstOrDefault().Value, out int defaultLangId);
            var serviceProvider = Context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILocalizationService>();
            

            if (_localizer == null)
            {
                _localizer = (format, args) =>
                {  //we want to set the default langauge id here so whatever the user sets will always be shown.
                    var resFormat = serviceProvider.GetResourceAsync(format, defaultLangId).Result;
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resFormat))
                    {
                        return new LocalizedString(format);
                    }
                    return new LocalizedString((args == null || args.Length == 0)
                        ? resFormat
                        : string.Format(resFormat, args));
                };
            }
            return _localizer;
        }
    }

}

 /// <summary>
 /// Web view page
 /// </summary>
 public abstract class CellaRazorPage : CellaRazorPage<dynamic>
 {
 }
}
```

Database Call have this in something like
LocalizationService

```
public virtual async Task<string> GetResourceAsync(string resourceKey, int langugeID)
{
    var result = await _context.LocaleStringResource.Where(w => w.ResourceName == resourceKey && w.LanguageId == langugeID && w.isDeleted == false && w.isActive == true).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        var resultString = string.Empty;
        if (result != null)
            resultString = result.ResourceValue;
        else
            resultString = resourceKey;
        return resultString;
}
```

Usage

## @T("Search")

This means you can update your strings live from the database, and on the next refresh it will contain the new string without a restart.

I forgot to mention that the languages would be stored like this. You would save this off in a cookie or your appsettings the language Id or if from a country selector like mine.

[image]

Save the id from here in a cookie

Here you would store your strings
[image]